# Android Emulator Skin Not applying

Tags: android

i want to apply skin for android emulator,i am copy the emulator skin paste to this location path `D:\android\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-8\skins` it does not show skins drop down box in android sdk..!

copy the skins from android sdk skins folder below screen shot:

[image]

and does not show the Nexus-s skin in dropdown box on eclipse below screen shot:

[image]

can any one help me..!
Thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find it under targets

pleas try this: put the file into `Android\android-sdk-windows\add-ons` and then check Target in AVD

Comment: i am paste skins android target-8 and select emulator target is 8.but, does not shows..!

Comment: i am tried copy files to Android\android-sdk-windows\add-ons.but, does not work

Comment: i restart my eclipse and then i got it in targets, strange